# Cast from '(key: String, value: AnyObject)' to unrelated type '[String : Any]' always

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to parse a JSON response and display it in a tableView using swift.

Here is the code:

```
do {
     let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
     print(fetchedData)

     for eachFetchedJourney in fetchedData{
         let eachJourney = eachFetchedJourney as! [String: Any]
         let line = eachJourney["line"] as! String
         let description = eachJourney["description"] as! String

         self.fetchedJourneys.append(Journey(line: line, description: description))
         print(fetchedData)
     }
     self.journeysTableView.reloadData()
 }
```

and I get the error:

```
Cast from '(key: String, value: AnyObject)' to unrelated type '[String : Any]' always fails
```

What is wrong?

The data looks like this: https://api.tfl.gov.uk/journey/journeyresults/1000266/to/1000013

Comment: There's no "line" key in that data. What is `line` expected to be? You're also not digging down to the "journeys" array, and the only thing I see with "description" in it is the "disruptions" array. It's not clear how the above code is supposed to relate to the data you linked.

Answer (score 1):

`fetchedData` is a dictionary. when you enumerate over a dictionary, you get tuples of `(key: Key, value: Value)`. It looks like you expect `fetchedData` to be an array, or perhaps you meant

```
for eachFetchedJourney in fetchedData.values
```

We can likely help you further if you will show what the JSON looks like.

Comment: The data looks like this: https://api.tfl.gov.uk/journey/journeyresults/1000266/to/1000013